# MultiThreading Vert.x to handling thousands of connections per sec

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm building up a messenger like server, I have made some changes to vert.x like this

```
vertx.deployVerticle(MainDeployment.class.getCanonicalName(),res -> {
          if (res.succeeded()) {

                Logger.Log("Deployed");

              } else {
                Logger.Log(res.cause().getMessage());
              }
            });

    server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(port);


 public void createContext(String path,MyHttpHandler handler){
    //handlersMap.put(path.split("\\/")[1], handler);
    if(!path.endsWith("/")){
        path += "/";
    }

    path+="*";

    map.put(path, handler);
}
```

and here my MainDeployment class

```
 public class MainDeployment extends AbstractVerticle{



  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {

      //GUI.display("Sub Verticle Has Deployed");

    // Different ways of deploying verticles

    // Deploy a verticle and don't wait for it to start

   for(Entry<String, MyHttpHandler> entry : MyVertxServer.map.entrySet()){
       MyVertxServer.router.route(entry.getKey()).handler(new Handler<RoutingContext>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {

                String[] handlerID = ctx.request().uri().split(ctx.currentRoute().getPath());

                String suffix = handlerID.length > 1 ? handlerID[1] : null;
                entry.getValue().Handle(ctx, new VertxUtils(), suffix);

            }
        });
   }

  }
}
```

the documentation says

```
 Vert.x guarantees that a particular verticle instance is never executed by more than one thread concurrently. This gives you a huge advantage as a developer, since you can program all your code as single threaded
```

since every verticle has its own thread and will be single threaded , so if my verticle upload files , it can not process 2 uploads at same time or am i misunderstanding the concept of NIO?

Comment: What does the sources provided have to do with the multi-thread issue?

Comment: nothing as far as i searched , but they all mention basic usages. soooo many examples but none of them provide such info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should dig deeper through the *Vert.x* documentation to get more familiar with the backing API and design.

The official documentation, which I highly advice, states the following:

> Even though a Vertx instance maintains multiple event loops, any particular handler will never be executed concurrently, and in most cases (with the exception of worker verticles) will always be called using the exact same event loop.

The *file upload* process that you are trying to implement, is considered a **blocking** operation thus should be executed:

- Either through using the blocking API `Vertx#executeBlocking`
- Or within a worker pool that can be obtained through `Vertx#createSharedWorkerExecutor` call

Both way will result in the *event-loop* thread not being halt with blocking operations (I'm stating **the** *event-loop* thread but we are actually talking about all the *event-loop* threads as they may be more than one).

Comment: so vertx is not useful for large scale file server?

Comment: Indeed it is, but you should design your application carefully so it can scale upon need.
Even a *file-upload* process is considered blocking, having many workers behinds (with a clustered configuration as a plus) can meet your requirements.

Comment: thanks alot . so i will handle durable works with executor and send , receive files with Pump and sendFile()